# angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker close calendar when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap

I'm totally new to angular and I try to use angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker in my project. My html code is:

```
<span class="input-group-btn" ng-class="{open: openedDP}">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="open()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <datetimepicker ng-model="abc"
                          on-set-time="close(new, old)">
          </datetimepicker>
      </ul>
</span>
<input id="abc" ng-model="abc" class="form-control" date-time-input="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS" />
```

I wanted to close a calendar when user clicks anywhere outside it. I almost copy-pasted the code from ui.bootstrap. Original one is inside directive and looks like this:

```
var documentClickBind = function(event) {
        if (scope.isOpen && event.target !== element[0]) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.isOpen = false;
          });
        }
      };

scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
        if (value) {
          scope.$broadcast('datepicker.focus');
          scope.position = appendToBody ? $position.offset(element) : $position.position(element);
          scope.position.top = scope.position.top + element.prop('offsetHeight');

          $document.bind('click', documentClickBind);
        } else {
          $document.unbind('click', documentClickBind);
        }
      });
```

My version (inside controller):

```
var documentClickBind = function (event) {
     if ($scope.openedDP) {
         $scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.openedDP = false;
         });
      }
 };

  $scope.$watch('openedDP', function (value) {
            if (value) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $document.bind('click', documentClickBind);
                }, 0, false);
            } else {
                $document.unbind('click', documentClickBind);
            }
        });
```

I removed "element" variable because I don't have it in my controller and it seems to work, but I don't know why. Maybe it works just by chance? Why clicking inside calendar is different than clicking anywhere else? In addition I'd like to avoid creating multiple functions like this when I have multiple datepickers on a page.

Comment: I guess you are referring to [this datetimepicker](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/). That's the default behavior, correct?

Comment: Without this piece of code I have to click to the same button again to close calendar.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is built-in to the bootstrap `dropdown`, if you have bootstrap already in your project you might consider making use of its `dropdown`.

If not, you could create a custom directive on the page that broadcasts a `'page-clicked'` event when the user clicks on another part of the page, then each controller can listen for that event on their scope and react accordingly.